# Deleting all empty elements from the end of a string array

Tags: c#, loops, iteration

I have the following code:

```
public static string[] Split(this string me, string splitter, bool remove_empty_elements = false)
{
    return me.Split(new string[] {splitter}, remove_empty_elements ? StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries : StringSplitOptions.None);
}

"ABCddcddd".Split("d")
```

and it generates a string array that looks like:

```
╭─────┬─────────┬───┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────╮
│ ABC │ <empty> │ c │ <empty> │ <empty> │ <empty> │
╰─────┴─────────┴───┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────╯
```

What's the best way to remove all empty string elements from end **and keep middle ones**? Right now I'm doing `"ABCddcddd".Split("d").Reverse().SkipWhile(x => x=="").Reverse()` and I don't feel very good about it.

Comment: Check the overloads of the string.split, [there is one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2) that removes empty results. Not adding an answer because it likely would be a duplicated question

Comment: @Cleptus I need to keep empty elements in the middle of the result and only remove beginning and ending empty elements.

Comment: "This code `"ABCdabcddd".Split("d")` generates a string array that looks like:" this code should generate a compiler error: CS1503...

Comment: Didnt notice, then I would call `string.TrimEnd('d').Split("d")`

Comment: Oh sorry, bad example. It's actually an extension method I defined. I'll update the code and description.